# html page disappears after onclick("open()") event

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote an html as

```
html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <span onclick = "open()">open</span>

<script src= "script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and javascript as

```
function open(){

   var id = "10";

}
```

whenever I click on the open text in the browser the whole page gets wiped out . Is "open" a reserved word in javascript as with any method name it works(screen doesn't get wiped out) . Just wondering what is happening behind the scene. Any information is appreciated.

Comment: According to [this source](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm) it is and it could be mixing up window events (maybe `window.open()`), but it's just a guess. Tried with `_open()` and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually came across a similar question recently - the reason this is happening is because `open()` is being interpreted as `window.open()`. When no parameters are passed into this function, it navigates to a blank window.

You might be able to circumvent this by putting your script in the head, but a better recommendation is to give your function a more meaningful name.

Side note: Not certain if the behavior is the same across browsers, but in Google Chrome, calling `open()` opens a new tab.

Further reading on the function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 1):

as a general rule you will have a lot of conflicts if you program that way - you need to be more modular - use objects/json for namespacing

```
<html>
   <body>
      <span onclick = "mylibrary.open()">open</span>

      <script src= "script.js"></script>

   </body>

</html>
```

and javascript as

```
var mylibrary = {
   open : function(){
      var id = "10";

   }

}
```

roughly ...